# Spring Boot org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, exception, rollback

```
    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/org/deleteqrcodepoint/{orgid}/{mobile}/{nameofqrcodepoint}"}, method= RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody public Object deleteteqrcodepoint(@PathVariable String orgid,@PathVariable String mobile,@PathVariable String nameofqrcodepoint) {
        Jsonmessageanddata jsondata=new Jsonmessageanddata();
        try {

            
            //orgmultipleqrcodeService.deleteByPoint(orgid,mobile,nameofqrcodepoint);
            Query query =  manager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM orgmultipleqrcode WHERE orgid="+orgid+" and mobile="+mobile+" and nameofqrcodepoint="+nameofqrcodepoint+" ", Orgmultipleqrcode.class);
            query.executeUpdate();
        
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            
        }
    }
```

Giving me following error:

```
Exception   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
[2m2021-10-01 15:58:22.311[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m10324[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8085-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only] with root cause

org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

When i am trying to delete record from mysql then not able to delete it.
also tried @Transactional but still not working and giving me error.

Comment: For the audience, has **no** sense use `@Transactional` in a `@Controller`/`@RestController`

Answer (score 2):

Propably the exectuion of your query lead to an exception.
Which you are silently ignoring here:

```
}catch(Exception e) {
            
}
```

after that the Transaction is marked as rollback

print the exception

```
}catch(Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();                
}
```

this will show you the error.
You have to put your values in ' ' this will be the error.

Better would be to work with query parameters:

```
 Query query =  manager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM orgmultipleqrcode WHERE orgid=:origid", Orgmultipleqrcode.class);

query.setParameter("origid", orgid);
query.executeUpdate();
```